# How to find the row in a matrix which is closest to a test row?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, find

I am currently trying to come up with a smart way to store my data, such that I can easily search, sort and insert.

My data consist of a `std::pair<vector<int>,string>` which is stored in a `std::vector`, forming sort of an 2d matrix.

Something like this:

[image]

Each vector has a number sequence that matches a `string`.

My problem here is when it should be tested.

A test, consist of testing it with a test vector, which might be the same length or be smaller than those stored in the matrix. how do I find out which string the test vector best matches with?

How do i search for that efficiently?

Some thought of ideas on how to solve the problem, and some of the problems with them:

- One idea was to make sub sums, depending on the length of the test vector, and then see which of the sub sums, best matches the sum of the test vector.

Problem: I am looking to the same pattern, so the same sum could occur given another pattern.

- Another idea was to make a copy of the matrix, sort it column wise, and make a search for a each index, and keep track of which the string were matching the best..

Problem:  This though requires sorting all the columns -  the matrix is way larger than showed above,  it has around 1000 columns, and it seems too expensive to make one search for a one sort -  given the amount of time I would spent on it - A insert possibility also need to be implemented, so something efficient would be appreciated.

Comment: "seems" - O(NlogN)scales pretty well, and 1000 is a pretty small data set in the general scheme of things.    In addition, rather than sort and take the first you could use [nth_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) and make it O(N) rather than O(NlogN)

Comment: I am not sure I understand the nth_element solution you are suggesting?

Comment: You want the closest item, and you suggested sorting;  which is the right idea.  The thing is you only want the ONE closest item; not all of them in order, so you don't need everything sorted.  That's what nth_element does.

Comment: Well it depends.. I still want to know how far the others are, which is why I keep track of them all...

Comment: So you want to sort them; which you already suggested; and you've not tested the performance to know that it's a problem.  So what's the question?

Comment: The question was whether there is a better alternative.. 1000 is still an undestatement.. 1000000...  But yes, I guess I have to test it with some run time, to see how big of an issue it is, it just seemed theoretically that doing all of this would seem too expensive..

Comment: Well, you could avoid making copies of the data and just have pointers to it - and then sort the pointers ... that would be a good start

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you could make sub hashing instead of sub sum. Effective hashing helps you to avoid collisions which could be a problem with sum.

Comment: @miradham but that would become pretty memory heavy.. 
And it would not help if the key being used for test isn't exactly the same as the one used in the hashing.  The test key is prone to noise, which is why I am looking for the best fits.

Comment: then what is the condition to be a "best match" of the test vector?

Comment: As an example lets say that each row in the matrix has 100 entries. 
A test would consist of an test vector which size is not a constant, but will be in-between 10 - 100.  A perfect match will be when the pattern seen in the test-vector can be found in the matrix anywhere..  A best match would be again finding the pattern, but with small deviation..